# NSDateFormatter timezone issue

Tags: swift, ios8, nsdate, nsdateformatter, nstimezone

I am trying to format an existing date in my project. Also, I am using `localTimeZone` to format date. However, it returns `UTC` and does not give correct date. Here is my code:

```
var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()
bagItem.date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateFormatter.stringFromDate(self.selectedDateForAdmin))
```

After the code above during debugging, for instance; today is `21-04-2015`. However, it returns `20-04-2015`. The actual question is that Why `NSTimezone.localTimeZone()` does not return correct date? Also, why returns `UTC`? I live in Turkey and timezone should be `GMT`. Please help me. This is a huge problem for my project.

Best regards

Comment: NSDate **does not have a time zone**. Its description **always use UTC**. (There are *many* similar questions with answers). If you want to present the date in the local timezone then you should convert the result of `stringFromDate()` back to an NSDate.

Comment: So, what is the best way to format a date for current local date and time ? @MartinR

Comment: `dateFormatter.stringFromDate(self.selectedDateForAdmin)` is already a formatted string in the local time zone.

Comment: Ok I got it. However I need to date as a NSDate type not string ? How can I get the date from formatted date with "stringFromDate" as correct date  @MartinR

Comment: NSDate describes an absolute point in time. Internally it is stored just as the number of seconds since Jan 1, 2001 GMT. NSDate does not know anything about time zones. So "NSDate in the local timezone" makes no sense!